# Unable to connect to the SQL database for cache dependency registration using aspnet_regsql

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I Want to enable SQL Server Dependency using Command Prompt in Visual Studio.

```
I am able to run on the local SQL Server using Windows authentication, but i 

only face the problem when running using SQL Server Authentication.
```

Comment: Please enable `remote connections` in `SQL Server` (Right click the sql server instance in `Management Studio`) and in the connections area make sure `named pipes` are enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try It

If you want to enable the SQL database for cache dependency registration with SQL Server Authentication using aspnet_regsql

```
Try these Steps with your credentials:-

 1. run command aspnet_regsql -ed -S servername -d databasename -U userid -P password 

-S Server Name
-d Database Name
-U SQL Server Login Id
-P Password

2. If you want on specific table then run the command :-aspnet_regsql -ed -S servername -d databasename -U userid -P password -et -t tablename.
```